# Which platform does not allow multiple FileWriters to open on a file

Tags: java

JAVA docs for [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) say

> Whether or not a file is available or may be created depends upon the
>    * underlying platform.  ***Some platforms, in particular, allow a file to be
>    * opened for writing by only one*** FileWriter (or other file-writing
>    * object) at a time.  In such situations the constructors in this class
>    * will fail if the file involved is already open."

I need to know what are the platforms which does not allow multiple `FIleWriter` on a file.

Thanks

Comment: Windows is certainly one of them, and Unix/Linux/Solaris almost certainly not. Note that this applies to nearly all ways of writing to a file, not just `FileWriter,` and to all combinations, not just two simultaneous instances of any one of them. `RandomAccessFile(..., "rw")` is an obvious exception.

Answer (score 1):

Windows platforms does not allow multiple FileWriter's on the same file.